# No value gets shown after using gin package to get data from Postman Form

Tags: go, postman, go-gin

Below is the code I've being working on. It shows a success message when it is run, but doesn't show the value defined in the post man form. Instead it shows blank spaces in command prompt.

```
package main

import (
"fmt"
"github.com/gin-gonic/gin"
)

func saveCustomer(c *gin.Context){
    fn := c.PostForm("firstName")
    ln := c.PostForm("lastName")
    em := c.PostForm("email")
    phnno := c.PostForm("phone_no")
    fmt.Printf("fn: %v; ln: %v ; em: %v ; phnno: %v ;",fn ,ln ,em ,phnno )
    c.String(200, "Success")
}
func main() {
    r := gin.Default()
    r.POST("/saveCustomer", saveCustomer)
    r.Run(":8080")
}
```

here, no values are shown, instead blank spaces are shown

[image]

and below is the postman data fields with success message.

[image]

Comment: Your code works fine on my machine, there must be something wrong with your postman settings. Also, this has absolutely nothing to do with unit testing or mongodb so please edit those tags out

Comment: Screenshot of your exact code (with just the print changed to be less of a mess) running fine with postman and the terminal logs: https://imgur.com/a/alq2kW1

Comment: Thanks for checking this  out , removed the tags.Created new collection  too  in postman, still  getting the issue

Comment: Try just creating a new request from scratch, using `http://localhost:8080` as the URL, switching to POST and setting the form-data fields. If it still does not work, try using a curl request instead: `curl -X POST \
  http://localhost:8080/saveCustomer \
  -H 'Cache-Control: no-cache' \
  -H 'Postman-Token: 0741a012-7dee-411a-9aa6-695d780025fb' \
  -H 'content-type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW' \
  -F firstName=John \
  -F lastName=Doe \
  -F email=john.doe@test.com \
  -F 'phone_no=+12 345 678 901'`

Answer (score 0):

maybe you should using x-www-form-urlencoded instead?

```
func main() {
router := gin.Default()

router.POST("/post", func(c *gin.Context) {

    id := c.Query("id")
    page := c.DefaultQuery("page", "0")
    name := c.PostForm("name")
    message := c.PostForm("message")

    fmt.Printf("id: %s; page: %s; name: %s; message: %s", id, page, name, message)
})
router.Run(":8080")
```

}

data post:

```
POST /post?id=1234&page=1 HTTP/1.1
```

Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

name=manu&message=this_is_great